# How to store data with database batch, efficiently and persistently?

Tags: java, queue

I want to store data which is actually a 1000 character text data, fast into database. How fast? Let's say 1000 data per second.

To be efficient, I use database feature called "batch insert". This is the snippet code to achieve it.

```
private Queue q;

public void store(MyData data) {
    q.add(data);
}

public void onStarted() {
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            while(true) {
                    if (q.notEmpty()) {
                        List someData = new ArrayList();
                        q.drainTo(someData, BATCH_SIZE);
                        storeWithSqlBatch(someData);
                    }
                    sleep(100);
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
```

But that's a bad code, since unsaved data only exists in memory. When, power loss, the data will be lost. I've been thinking using JMS Queue with persistent=true. But I don't really know the recommended way.

Comment: If power loss is a genuine threat, you'd be better off investing into some UPS equipment. This is not a situation that can or should be fixed by not using batch inserts.